# How to load non static images from an array into collection view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to get images URL'S from my firebase firestore and save them in an array.

then I would like to set up a collection view that would display the images in the array in a sliding manner similar to Instagram (horizontally).

I am retrieving the values of my images url's and saving them in variables and then setting them in an array, but when I set up my collection view it does not work, I believe that the collection view functions receive the array with empty values since I am retrieving and storing them in the view did load method

what am I doing wrong?

any help on this? thank you.
here is my code:

```
public var imgArray = [URL]()
var getHeaderURL : URL!
var getHeaderURL2 : URL!
var getHeaderURL3: URL!
var getHeaderURL4: URL!

var headerImgURL:String!
var headerImgURL2:String!
var headerImgURL3:String!
var headerImgURL4:String!
override func viewDidLoad(){

db.collection("Shops").document(getKey!)
        .addSnapshotListener { [self] snapshot, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "Couldn't update text field TextUser according to database")
            }
            else
            {
     
                //getting url's as strings
                self.headerImgURL = snapshot?["ShopHeaderImg"] as? String
                self.headerImgURL2 = snapshot?["ShopHeaderImg2"] as? String
                self.headerImgURL3 = snapshot?["ShopHeaderImg3"] as? String
                self.headerImgURL4 = snapshot?["ShopHeaderImg4"] as? String
            }
             //converting url strings into url type.
             getHeaderURL = URL(string: self.headerImgURL)
             getHeaderURL2 = URL(string: self.headerImgURL2)
             getHeaderURL3 = URL(string: self.headerImgURL3)
             getHeaderURL4 = URL(string: self.headerImgURL4)
            
             self.imgArray = [getHeaderURL!,getHeaderURL2!,getHeaderURL3!,getHeaderURL4!]
             print(imgArray)
  }
```

my collection view functions:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(imgArray.count)
    print("this is the count of images")
    return imgArray.count
   
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = imageCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imgCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCellViewController
    
    
    cell.sliderImage.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
    cell.sliderImage.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
    cell.sliderImage.sd_setImage(with: imgArray[indexPath.row], placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Profile_avatar_placeholder_large"))
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Have you set up datasource for collectionView? also you should call super.viewDidLoad()

Comment: When are you reloading the collection view? Please use an `array` instead of hardcoded variables.

Comment: @MishaVyrko yes i did, but i didnt include in the question to make it more simple to understand, even super.view did load is included in my code but forgot to include in the question.

Comment: @Rob when i reload the collectionview it gives me an error saying "sliderimage is not coding compliant ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `reloadData()` on your collection view after the line that you fill `imgArray`.